# Checkbox Inputs with same name not fireing javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, input

I'm new to the web development world.
I have an app build on ASP. NET MVC.

There is a list of checkboxes generated with Razor

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(m => m.Visible))
{
<input id="selectedValues" name="selectedValues" type="checkbox" @(item.Selected ? "checked" : "") />
}
```

and a Javascript function that triggers a Ajax action:

```
$('#selectedValues').change(function () {

var data = {};
data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).is(':checked');

$.ajax({
   url: '@Url.Action("action", "controller")',
   type: 'POST',
   data: data,
   success: function (result) {

   }
 });
});
```

In model I have some items and the list of checkboxes is build ok on html.
The problem is that only the first checkbox is triggering an action on the controller. Both when I select unselect it.

The rest of checkboxes **don't** trigger the action.

Any idea how this can be resolved? Many Thanks!

Comment: I put the same ID/name to receive in controller a List of the selected.

Comment: Remove the ID and use the name instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They may not have same ID and # is ID, not name

```
$('input[name="selectedValues"]')
```

will work better

Or

```
<input class="selectedValues" name="selectedValues"
```

using

```
$(".selectedValues")
```

Lastly use .on("click" instead of change since change is not triggered without a blur in some browsers

Comment: Many Thanks! I understud the problem and it's working.